# makefile generate target fail with % cant't replace my path

Tags: makefile

where my local dir exit file ./utils/.StrUtils.cpp
errMsg = target `utils/.StrUtils.d' doesn't match the target pattern

```
local = ./utils/.StrUtils.d
$(local):.%.d:%.cpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@;
```

but when i change this code to

```
local = ./utils/.StrUtils.d
.%.d:%.cpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@;
```

it can run well, i cant't understand why，who can give some good advance，i will be greatly appreciated

my total code like this,  i just simplify the problem as front

$(LOCAL_DEPENDS):.%.d:%.cpp  get error

$(LOCAL_HPP):.%.d:%.hpp      get error

.%.d:%.cpp                   get right

.%.d:%.hpp                   get right

```html
TARGET           := ./bin/Main
CC               := gcc 
CXX              := g++ 
CFLAGS           := -lpthread -g -Wall
LFLAGS           := -L./lib 

INC_DIR          :=./utils .
SRC_DIR          :=./utils . 

LOCAL_SRC        := $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIR), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp $(dir)/*.c $(dir)/*.cc))
LOCAL_HPP        := $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIR), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.hpp))
LOCAL_INC        := $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIR))

LOCAL_OBJS        = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o, $(patsubst %.c,%.cpp,$(patsubst %.cc,%.cpp,$(LOCAL_SRC))))

LOCAL_DEPENDS    := $(LOCAL_SRC:%.cpp=%.d)
LOCAL_DEPENDS    := $(foreach file, $(LOCAL_DEPENDS), $(dir $(file)).$(notdir $(file)))

LOCAL_HPP        := $(foreach file, $(LOCAL_HPP), $(dir $(file)).$(basename $(notdir $(file))).d)

$(TARGET): $(LOCAL_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LOCAL_OBJS) -o $@ $(LOCAL_INC)

$(LOCAL_OBJS):%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LOCAL_INC)

-include $(LOCAL_DEPENDS)
$(LOCAL_DEPENDS):.%.d:%.cpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@;\
    $(CXX) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(LOCAL_INC) $< > $@.$$$$;\
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[:]*,\1.o $@:,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;\
    rm $@.$$$$

-include $(LOCAL_HPP)
$(LOCAL_HPP):.%.d:%.hpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@;\
    $(CXX) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(LOCAL_INC) $< > $@.$$$$;\
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[:]*,\1.o $@:,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;\
    rm $@.$$$$

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET); rm -f $(LOCAL_OBJS); rm -f $(LOCAL_DEPENDS); rm -f $(LOCAL_HPP)
```

Comment: Please provide the path of your source file, the command you typed, and the error you got when you ran make (cut and paste please).

Comment: You showed enough of your makefile in your original post: we didn't need to see the rest.  You still didn't show us the parts we really needed to see, that I asked for in my previous comment, which are the path to the source file and the error messages make prints when you try to use the static pattern rule version.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the path to the source file we can't be sure, but most likely the difference is due to this [special behavior of pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html):

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix.

So for a target pattern `.%.d` (there is no slash here) and a target `./utils/.StrUtils.d`, the stem will be `StrUtils` with a directory prefix of `./utils/`, and so the prerequisite pattern `%.cpp` will match a source file `./utils/StrUtils.cpp`.

However, IIRC static pattern rules don't have this special behavior, so this:

```
./utils/.StrUtils.d : .%.d : %.cpp
```

has a pattern match of `/utils/.StrUtils` and is the same as writing:

```
./utils/.StrUtils.d : /utils/.StrUtils.cpp
```

The error message you get should tell you as much, but you didn't show us that either.

Comment: i don't know  whether or not exit a  rule can fix this problem
in this case,  is i must write like ".%.d:%.cpp",    in my opinion this way i feel not enought perfect

Comment: i understand what you said  Suddenly，thanks in advance。